# how to create a table in a word 2003 document using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2003

I have a template for a report that needs to get filled out and i am automating the process.

There is a part of the template a couple pages down that has multiple identical tables to input data.

What I am trying to do is have a user control with a text box where the user can input a number and then the document generates the number of tables specified.

I am not sure where to start and how to specify where the tables are to be generated in relation to the rest of the document,

Comment: Have you tried using the Macro Recorder yet?  I think if you turned it on, created the table and then looked at the code you would have what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Created the base code via the macro recorder and then added the vars and loop:

```
Sub tableMake()

    Dim numberOfTables As Integer
    Dim iCount As Integer

    numberOfTables = InputBox("How many tables to make?", "Tables")

    For iCount = 0 To numberOfTables - 1

        ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:= _
            3, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
            wdAutoFitFixed
        With Selection.Tables(1)
            If .Style <> "Table Grid" Then
                .Style = "Table Grid"
            End If
            .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
            .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
            .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
            .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
            '.ApplyStyleRowBands = True 'Office 2010
            '.ApplyStyleColumnBands = False 'Office 2007
        End With

        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
        Selection.TypeParagraph

    Next iCount

End Sub
```

Comment: Hm, i've been trying to make this work but I have to edit the table's cells, like merging certain ones and adding text to some, but it is throwing all kinds of errors

Comment: Are you saying you get errors when the code above runs or, after the code is run and you try to do your editing?  I have Office 2010 so it's possible some of the properties above are not backwards compatible.  Otherwise, I need more info on the specific error(s) you're getting.

Comment: Method or data member not found on ".ApplyStyleRowBands"

Comment: It's a backwards compatibility issue.  I commented out the code that is the problem and tested in Office XP (which came out around 2002).  That should work.